# Use the formal definition to prove that the following sequence diverges

Tags: real-analysis

$\displaystyle s_n=\left(\frac1n-1\right)^n$

**My attempt:**

For large $n$, the sequence oscillates between $e^{-1}$ and $-e^{-1}$ and therefore diverges. Now for the proof.

Assume, for the sake of argument, that the sequence converges to $L$.

$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|s_n-L|<0.1$ whenever $n\ge N$

$\displaystyle\left|\left(\frac1n-1\right)^n-L\right|<0.1$ whenever $n\ge N$

$\displaystyle\implies\left|\left(\frac1{n+1}-1\right)^{n+1}-L\right|<0.1$ whenever $n\ge N$

We can rewrite these 2 equations as

$\displaystyle\left|(-1)^n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n-L\right|<0.1$ whenever $n\ge N$ --------------- (1)

$\displaystyle\left|(-1)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-L\right|<0.1$ whenever $n\ge N$

$\displaystyle\implies\left|(-1)^n\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+L\right|<0.1$ whenever $n\ge N$ --------------- (2)

How do I get a contradiction from equations (1) and (2)?

Comment: You know that $(1-\frac1n)^n$ is monotonically increasing and greater $1/4$ for $n>2$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\left(\frac1n-1\right)=(-1)\left(1-\frac1n\right)$, we can write
$$s_n = (-1)^n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n. $$
It is clear then that
$$s_{2n} = \left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{2n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow e^{-1}, $$
which implies $\limsup_{n\to\infty} s_n\geqslant e^{-1}$, and similarly
$$s_{2n+1} = -\left(1-\frac1{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow -e^{-1}$$
which implies $\liminf_{n\to\infty} s_n\leqslant -e^{-1}$. It follows that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}s_n \ne \limsup_{n\to\infty}s_n, $$ and so the sequence $s_n$ does not converge.